# Auto generate by default, first two digits are the last two digits of current year

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to work with MS SQL functions. Project number should be
automatically generated by default, first two digits are the last two digits of the current year, then ‘-’ then the last three digits are serial number based on the year.

e.g 16-000 then next will be 16-001 so on but when 2017 comes it will change again 17-000 and continue.

Comment: this is not a script-coding service. Show some some invention and *what you tried so far*.

Comment: You can always achieve this with your backend language too. You've not said whether you're wanting an update statement or a stored procedure (though I think this is too broad and/or unclear, so have voted to put on hold - as Jakuje says, let's see your code and research please).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my achievement and need some kind of modification as it throws exception "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '16-001' to data type int." when this portion is being execute.
 set @pId =(SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), year(GETDATE()), 1),2))  +'-'+ RIGHT(@pId,3)+1

My function complete code.

create function NextProjectNumber() 
    returns char(6) 
    as 
    begin
   declare @pId varchar(50), @pYear int, @serial varchar(3), @currYear int
    SELECT @pId = ProjectId from [JobPortalDb].[dbo].[Projects] where  ProjectId=(select max(ProjectId) from [JobPortalDb].[dbo].[Projects])
    Set @currYear = (SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), year(GETDATE()), 1),2))
     --SELECT @pId,@year

If @pId IS NULL set @pId = (SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), year(GETDATE()), 1),2))+'-001'
   else set  @pYear = SUBSTRING(@pId, 1, 2)

if @pYear = @currYear 
   set @pId =(SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), year(GETDATE()), 1),2))  +'-'+ RIGHT(@pId,3)+1

if @currYear > @pYear
   set @pId = (SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), year(GETDATE()), 1),2)) +'-001'

return @pId
   end

Comment: if i exclude  +'-'+  then result is 16002 and i need 16-002